# Strange Issue product image filename adding _1 to the filename

Tags: magento-1.9

I am adding new products , and I want to copy the images , and keep them with the same name.  In most cases it seems to work , but one particular product ( and possibly others ) has me baffled.

- I have deleted ALL products
- I have deleted ALL images in media/catalog/product
- I have disabled the cache , redindxed and I have even a run magerun addon to remove any orphan references / orphan files.

I am using addImagetoMediaGallery

```
$targetProduct->addImageToMediaGallery($importFilepath,$sourceImage['types'],false,$sourceImage['exclude']);
```

The image is set up correctly in terms of linking to the product and correct types , however it persists in adding a _1 to the and of the first part of the filename

So:

**th_new-l_4_2.jpg**

becomes

**th_new-l_4_2_1.jpg**

( Yes I do realise that it already has numbers appended from previous database )

**Note:** For other products , it seems to keep the filename as is.

This image does not exist anywhere that I can find in either the file system or the database ( I have been through pretty much all of the product / attribute / media tables.

If you have any idea why it would be doing this when the product does not exist I would appreciate your time.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok - figured it out.  The file was in \media\tmp\catalog\product\t\h

I didn't even know that that directory existed / was part of the process as a temporary place to put the file. somehow the file was "stuck" there. I spent way too long finding that.